# Google Earth hide geometry except for a small area

Tags: geometry, google-earth

In a Google Earth tour, I only want to show a specific small area, that is, I want to hide (not render) all terrain outside of this area. If such hiding is impossible, can I use a black "image overlay" with a transparent "hole" in it, to "drape over" most of the terrain except for a small area?

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could create a black polygon with a hole in the center and import that. I am just not sure how well google earth would load.

Comment: Hm, this may work. I'll give it a try.